# How to fill a score matrix in objective-C (for performing a sequence alignment)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, matrix, nsmutablearray

Im interested in doing some matrix calculations in objective-C (for an iPhone app).

A score should be calculated for every element in the matrix, but I can't even get my initialization of the matrix to work.
The algorithm i'm trying to implement is called the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm, is used to align nucleotide sequences.

Currently, I am trying to initialize a 2d array, be defining an array, and then fill every element of the array with another array, but it does not seem to work. 
My current go looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)alignSequences:(id)sender {
NSString *dnaString1 = @"GAATTCAGTTA";
NSString *dnaString2 = @"GGATCGA";

int intSections = (dnaString1.length+1);
int intRows = (dnaString2.length+1);


//The matrix is initialized, and the value of every element is set to 0
NSMutableArray *horizontalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intSections];

for (int i=0; i <= intSections; i++) {
    [horizontalArray insertObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intSections] atIndex:i];

    for (int j=0; j <= intRows; j++) {
        [[[horizontalArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] atIndex:j];
    }
}    

NSLog(@"%@",[[horizontalArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:1]);
}
```

Any ideas how to acomplish this? (I'm a newbie to objective-C, so sorry if there are stupid questions or obvious errors in the code)

Comment: What kind of compiler error are you getting?

Comment: The ouput looks like this:      `2012-05-04 22:51:26.236 prove[24775:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c7022 0x1558cd6 0x13b3d88 0x203a 0x13c8e99 0x1414e 0x140e6 0xbaade 0xbafa7 0xba266 0x393c0 0x395e6 0x1fdc4 0x13634 0x12b1ef5 0x139b195 0x12ffff2 0x12fe8da 0x12fdd84 0x12fdc9b 0x12b07d8 0x12b088a 0x11626 0x1c4d 0x1bb5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yowza! It's been a while... here goes nothing:

```
NSMutableArray *horizontalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intSections];

for (int i=0; i <= intSections; i++) {

    NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intRows];

    for (int j=0; j <= intRows; j++) {
        [innerArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    }

    [horizontalArray addObject:innerArray];
    [innerArray release];
}
```

Assuming it works, this is a little cleaner and it should do what you're attempting without inviting indexing errors. On that note, it looks like you're initializing your inner array with more space than necessary. This won't cause an indexing error, but observe:

```
[horizontalArray insertObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intSections] atIndex:i];
```

I think it would be better like this:

```
[horizontalArray insertObject:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intRows] atIndex:i];
```